# Why are compiler hint lines preceded by [DCC Warning]?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

Compiler hints are being included in the build messages as warnings when I compile any project on my installation of Delphi 2007, like so:

> [DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(30): H2077 Value assigned to 'i' never used

In my real project this persists even when I disable Show hints in the project options, however in a new test project this setting does hide these lines. Other people seem to see hints preceded by *[DCC Hint]*, is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Not to nag, but why do you care about this - shouldn't your code just compile without warnings and messages? They are there for a reason

Comment: Hints and warnings are quite different: a) hints should not impact the running of your code and can often be legitimately ignored; and b) you can't disable specific hints. eg see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/632328/139560

Comment: I would never ignore either. Hints may be ignored, but they are a sign that something is not quite right, so I would not ignore them.

Answer (score 2):

[The QC entry reporting this issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=44476) eight years ago was closed because it couldn't be reproduced, so there is likely no fix.

You might try deleting your project's *.dsk* file. That sometimes helps make spurious IDE issues go away.

Your most immediate course of action is "tweaking the code," as compiler developer Allen Bauer suggests in [the answer you cited in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/632328/33732). Hints might still indicate problems in your code, such as unfinished algorithms. When you get complacent about compiler messages, then you're less likely to notice when a new one crops up that really does require attention.

Eventually, you'll want to upgrade to a more recent Delphi version.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't actually want to hide hints, but I would like to be able to easily distinguish between hints and warnings.

Comment: In my experience, most people don't care to distinguish between them. Rather, *any* compiler message is a message that must be addressed immediately.

Comment: I'd rather eliminate all hints and warnings in my code, making the difference between them irrelevant.

Comment: As an example is it better to use `StrToInt` in a `try...except` block rather than `Val` because of _H2077 Value assigned to 'i' never used_?

Comment: If you're getting a message from using `Val`, then I suppose you're not checking for errors. That's easy to fix. Also consider `TryStrToInt` or `StrToIntDef`. The main reason to use `Val` is if you need the `Code` parameter to tell you which character caused the conversion to stop. If you don't use that parameter, then the compiler will tell you. (It tells you about *that* unused "var" parameter and not others because `Val` is compiler magic that gets inlined *before* the compiler performs its data-flow analysis to detect unused variables.)

Comment: The compiler message comes because the resultant int is not being used.

Comment: I see. You want to know whether a string contains an integer, but you don't care what value it has. Use `TryStrToInt`. The "unused" var parameter from that function won't trigger a hint from the compiler because the compiler considered all var parameters to be used (except the one for `Val`, because that function is magic).